# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Getting the error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

from the `if` condition in the component below.

I understand this error seems to happen when we are missing binding to a callback method. But in this case ... there is no callback method (since `rendor()` is calling the child components) and so I assume there shouldn't be a binding required.

Any help or pointers appreciated. Thanks.

```
class MasterProductTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inCart: Array(this.props.products.length).fill(false),
        };
    }

    render() {

        var inCartProds = [];
        var notInCartProds = [];
        this.props.products.forEach(function (product, i) {
            if (this.state.inCart[i] === true) {
                inCartProds.push(product);
            } else {
                notInCartProds.push(product);
            }
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <AvailableProducts products={notInCartProds} />
                <Cart products={inCartProds}  />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try binding the `forEach`(passing 2nd arg as this) like `this.props.products.forEach(function(){...}, this);`

Comment: You just solved @Panther thanks a ton !